# Jquery: Get Maximum value in An Array of Numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, numbers, highest

With jquery, how can I get the maximum value in an array or numbers?

Example:

```
var myArray = [1,4,7,3,12,0]
```

Expected Output:-

maximum value = 12

Comment: [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) is plain JavaScript

Comment: this is not array.lenght, lenght here is like array count.

Comment: You really need to be more clear in your question, then. A couple examples would help us understand what you mean.

Comment: Do you mean the last element? The maximum value? The number of elements in the array?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

if by highest number you mean max value you don't need jQuery. You could do:

```
var myArray = [9,4,2,93,6,2,4,61,1];
var maxValueInArray = Math.max.apply(Math, myArray);
```

Comment: Using ES6 you could do `Math.max( ...myArray );`